# ARKit: how to temporarily detach the camera and look at a specific node

Tags: swift4, arkit, scncamera

I have an ARKit SCNScene from which the user can pick a moving object from (tap on screen). How to detach ARKit camera so that I can setup up the camera to look at the moving object from the anchor point the camera was?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This would only move all your virtual objects while the camera image won't move and completely break the immersion of the user

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for: enable user to switch between AR mode to 3D mode in one frame (I'll reconstruct the environnement for the transition) @orangenkopf

Comment: In theory you can add additional cameras to your scene and change the active on by changing your renders `pointOfView`. I don't know how ARKit will behave though, it may hold a reference to the specific camera it created or tries to set the transform of the pointOfView